# I asked for 10 days leave from my company, they are not allowing me

Tags: termination, leave-of-absence

**What should I do?**

I asked for 10 days leave from my company but they are only granting me 2 days leave. I have explained everything in a letter, but they are not granting me 10 days leave.

My boss emailed me this:

> I cannot grant you a leave for 10 days, it is not possible and If you
>   will not come for next 10 days then I will fire you from the job.

I don't want to leave the job and there's a family issue. I have to go to another state with my family. My job is very important for me. My boss never behaved like this before. This is the first time I've asked for 10 days leave in 3 years.

What is the possible solution for this?

Comment: What does your contract say about extended leave? In every job I've ever had, whether or not to approve time off has always been at my boss's discretion.  If you have to help your family, it sounds like it might be time to find another job.

Comment: where are you located? maybe there is some workers Union you can contact

Comment: Are you member of a trade union?

Comment: Hi, this depends on where you work, and your contract. Please indicate what jurisdiction you work in, and what your contract and/or employee handbook says on vacation rules.

Comment: There is no real way to provide a valid answer without knowing your location, details in your contract, and details of the family issue. For instance, if you live in the US (where I am) and meet certain qualifications, and the "family issue" is that you need to care for a seriously ill family member, then the employer is required to grant you the 10 days (unpaid, if you don't have PTO to cover it), and your job is legally protected - they cannot fire you. Your question needs to be edited to include additional details if you want any more of an answer than @JoeStrazzere gave you in his comment.

Answer (score 17):

Your boss has not granted you holiday so you can't take it without risking being fired. That much is clear. **Can you request unpaid leave on compassionate grounds?** If not then you have to decide which is more important: attending to this family matter or keeping your job.

Check your contract for rules on taking leave due to extenuating circumstances. Also check your countries laws.